# Send emails from AWS EC2 instance

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp

I'm developing a .Net application that sends emails (such as confirmation or notification emails) to customers using 3rd party smtp server.

**Problem** - The emails are being sent perfectly in development environment but not from an EC2 instance.

I have filled-in the form as given in the [Link](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request)

I'm having trouble understanding Elastic IP address. Ive put in the SMTP IP address that i have in Elastic IP Address and Reverse DNS.

What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what appears in your logs when you attempt to send mail? have you tried using SES?